# Error in C++ compiling

Tags: c++

So I just started to learn the basics and I tried making a response for a number thing but it gives me an "std::" bind error for the 10th and 13th line. 
Here is the code (P.S I think the last curly bracket was left behind):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string name;
  int FavNum;
  cout << "Hello Sir what is your name" << endl;
  cin >> name >> "\n";

  cout << "Well Hello " << name
       << "What is your Favorite number between 1 and 100" << endl;
  cin >> name >> "\n";
  if (FavNum > 100) {
    cout << "Wow you like big numbers, but sorry you cant use that one" << endl;
  } else if (FavNum >= 90) {
    cout << "Wow you like huge numbers!" << endl;
  } else if (FavNum <= 10) {
    cout << "Wow you like smaller numbers!!!" << endl;
  } else if (FavNum == 13) {
    cout << "Wow your favorite number is the most unluckiest number in the "
            "whole entire universe and I don't know many people that would "
            "choose this number I'm proud comrad"
         << endl;
  } else if (FavNum <= 89) {
    cout << "You have a very nice number thats average try again!" << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: `cin >> name >> "\n";` - are you attempting to read into `"\n"`?

Answer (score 3):

```
cin >> name >> "\n";
```

should be

```
cin >> name;
```

in both places you used it. You cannot send an input stream to a string literal.

Comment: Thank you very much but I have one more question it always reverts to you like small numbers and I do not understand why?

Comment: But it would be good have such feature, with semantic read the `name` until `'\n'`

Comment: @lions2020 Make sure that the name you read doesn't have spaces. `cin` reads until the first white space. So if your name has spaces in it, `cin` will only read its first part, and the second part will be left in the stream. Use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) in case you need to read a full line containing spaces.

Comment: @user1034749 [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) can do exactly that.

Comment: @vsoftco No, I mean it should work in general case, like this `std::cin >> "Begin: " >> name >> "end"` and with such input `"Begin: aaa end"` we get `name == "aaa"`

Comment: @lions2020 I see another error (which is what causes your issue). The second `cin` should be `cin >> FavNum;` instead of `cin >> name;`. Your current code uses `FavNum` un-initialized (and probably it happens to be zero).

Comment: @user1034749 Oh I see. Yes, it looks interesting, although the implementation is probably quite nasty, since you'd need to link `cin` and `cout` together via `operator >>`.

Comment: @vsoftco But `scanf` can work with similar semantic without problems, for example `scanf("Begin: %s end\n", buf);`

Comment: @user1034749 No it doesn't. You cannot display output with `scanf`.

Comment: @vsoftco I didn't mean display output, I mean parsing input